# Postfix -- virtual_mailbox_domains are rejected

Tags: server, postfix

### I am running Postfix 3.4.13 on Ubuntu 20.04.

#### How I broke it:

I tried to configure virtual mailboxes for each subdomain (main.cf and referenced files listed in full lower in this post).

- I removed @mydomain.tld from mydestination=
- I set virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains
- I removed Unix user in virtual_alias_maps= parameter.
- I defined locations for the virtual mailboxes. I created the directories and subdirectories in accordance with maildir expected layout (cur new tmp) in the virtual base directory.

#### The Error:

After creating the virtual mailboxes, I get the following error when mailing to contact@mydomain.tld from a gmail account.

```
... connect from mail-qt1-f169.google.com[209.85.160.169]
... Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-qt1-f169.google.com[209.85.160.169]
... NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-qt1-f169.google.com[209.85.160.169]: 554 5.7.1 <contact@mydomain.tld>: **Relay access denied;** from=<****@gmail.com> to=<contact@mydomain.tld> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-qt1-f169.google.com>
... disconnect from mail-qt1-f169.google.com[209.85.160.169] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 bdat=0/1 quit=1 commands=5/7
```

If I go into /etc/postfix/main.cf and specify mydestination=mydomain.tld, then the new error is:

```
... connect from mail-qk1-f177.google.com[209.85.222.177]
... Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-qk1-f177.google.com[209.85.222.177]
... NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-qk1-f177.google.com[209.85.222.177]: 550 5.1.1 <contact@mydomain.tld>: **Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table;** from=<***@gmail.com> to=<contact@mydomain.tld> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-qk1-f177.google.com>
```

### This leads my to believe that my virtual mailbox domains are not working...

I have /etc/postfix/main.cf configured as this:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = localhost
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = lamp, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 2
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only=no
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout=3600s
tls_random_source=dev:/dev/urandom

virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps

virtual_minimum_uid = 100
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
```

- aliases

> postmaster: root

- /etc/mailname

> mydomain.tld

- /etc/postfix/virtual

> postmaster@mydomain.tld Unix account

- virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains (I 'postmapped' the file)

> virtual_mailbox_domains = mydomain.tld, wordpress.mydomain.tld, sentmail.mydomain.tld, imports.mydomain.tld, [www.mydomain.tld](http://www.mydomain.tld)

- virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail

> Maybe I did not create the mailboxes correctly? I created them manually, each having with a subdirectory called "contact". Inside "contact", I made "new", "tmp", and "cur" subdirectories, and I recursively changed the /var/spool/mail/domain ownership to mailuser:mailuser. The mode is 700 on the files/folders. Maybe that's not enough?

- virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps ( I "postmapped' the file)

> contact@mydomain.tld  mydomain.tld/contact/
> contact@wordpress.mydomain.tld    wordpress.mydomain.tld/contact/
> contact@sentmail.mydomain.tld sentmail.mydomain.tld/contact/
> contact@imports.mydomain.tld  imports.mydomain.tld/contact/
> contact@www.mydomain.tld  [www.mydomain.tld/contact/](http://www.mydomain.tld/contact/)
> @mydomain.tld         mydomain.tld/catchall/

- virtual_uid_maps = static:5000 <- this user exists. It is called "mailuser" and owns the mailboxes.
- virtual_gid_maps = static:5000 <- this group exists. It is called "mailuser" and g-owns the mailboxes.

I am not sure why my virtual domains are not 'presenting'. Maybe I cannot used hashed virtual_mailbox_domains and virtual_mailbox_maps files? I will try using unhashed files...

Of course I have tried restarting postfix.

EDIT: using unhashed files changed nothing.

Comment: since the original problem is 'Relay access denied' , I would advise you to (temporarily) switch verbose mode by adding -v parameter to the smtpd daemon in master.cf . You would then see all the processings that lead to 'Relay access denied'